# Going prone whilst climbing

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, conditions, falling

Recently I was running a game and my players were in a fight with a Young Red Dragon that was climbing a wall. One of my players was able to inflict the prone condition on it. We then had the conundrum:

Does a creature with a climbing speed that is climbing a wall, remain clung to the wall when knocked prone or does it fall from the wall, to the floor?

I have seen questions in regards to this with Spider Climb but that is a magical effect so the rules may differ.

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate, the linked question should address your question here.